# Continuous Sync

Tags: vpn, sync, dropbox, transparency, continuous-operation

I'm looking for a open source software to synchronize two folders in a Private Network (or a VPN) in a continuous/transparent way. Like DropBox, for exemple, but without the server aspects.

I found plethora of software that allowed to do that manually (or to planned it with a basic scheduler) This is not what i'm looking for.

Thanx for your eventual answers.

Comment: what OS are you running on these servers?

Answer (score 0):

Some external hard drives that have network connectivitity can be configured in such a way.  This is a [Western Digital Example](http://www.wdc.com/en/products/products.aspx?id=620)  As long as the client can access the hard drive(VPN/LAN), the data can be synced using software(WDSmartWare from Western Digital).  Works well for me but upload speed can be a bottleneck